# Tailwind new screen addition in config leads to not working of default break point

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Hai I am using tailwind for my react project. when I add a new custom screen breakpoint in the config the old screen break point like "sm" "md" "lg" all stopped working , class is not coming to the html.once I removed the new added breakpoint it started working fine.

I am using tailwind with react, installed following the official guide in tailwindcss.

And on the side note i am not able to use the default colors also.

NOTE: I build this along notous react starter pack

My tailwind config.

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: {
        50: "#fefffe",
        150: "#4f4f4f",
        250: "#d7dce1",
        350: "rgb(127, 139, 153)",
        450: "rgb(235, 238, 241)",
        550: "rgb(104, 109, 115)",
        650: "rgb(228, 228, 231)",
      },
      red: {
        50: "#DA0037",
      },
      green: {
        50: "rgb(40, 191, 123)",
      },
      iceberg: {
        DEFAULT: "#DFF4F3",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#FFFFFF",
        300: "#FFFFFF",
        400: "#FFFFFF",
        500: "#DFF4F3",
        600: "#B9E7E5",
        700: "#93DAD7",
        800: "#6DCDC8",
        900: "#47C0BA",
      },
      "black-squeeze": {
        DEFAULT: "#DDE7F2",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#FFFFFF",
        300: "#FFFFFF",
        400: "#FFFFFF",
        500: "#DDE7F2",
        600: "#B8CDE4",
        700: "#93B3D6",
        800: "#6E99C8",
        900: "#497FBA",
      },
      "pigeon-post": {
        DEFAULT: "#B9BBDF",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#FFFFFF",
        300: "#FFFFFF",
        400: "#DCDDEF",
        500: "#B9BBDF",
        600: "#9699CF",
        700: "#7377BF",
        800: "#5055AF",
        900: "#40448C",
      },
      "polo-blue": {
        DEFAULT: "#878ECD",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#F3F4FA",
        300: "#CFD2EB",
        400: "#ABB0DC",
        500: "#878ECD",
        600: "#636CBE",
        700: "#4650A8",
        800: "#373F84",
        900: "#282E60",
      },
    },
    screens:{
      pc:"1450px",
    },
    extend: {
      zIndex: {
        "-10": "-10",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

My package json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.3",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated.
For now I am doing adding all colors to custom and adding all screen breakpoints to config.
Is there any other way to make it both work without this mudane task.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep the default themes and add your own break-points, you must add the new break-points under extend section.

example:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {      /* any styles mentioned here will replace default classes */
    colors: {
      white: {
        50: "#fefffe",
        150: "#4f4f4f",
        250: "#d7dce1",
        350: "rgb(127, 139, 153)",
        450: "rgb(235, 238, 241)",
        550: "rgb(104, 109, 115)",
        650: "rgb(228, 228, 231)",
      },
      red: {
        50: "#DA0037",
      },
    },
    screens:{
      pc:"1450px",
    },
    extend: {    /* mention your styles under this section */
      zIndex: {
        "-10": "-10",
      },
    screens:{
      pc:"1450px",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**IMPORTANT**
If you want to extend a small breakpoint, you need to mention it along with all existing breakpoints (multiple small breakpoints should be mentioned in the order from smallest to largest)

Example from tailwindcss documentation

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xs': '475px',
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `screens` you need to specify whole object of breakpoints (defaults included) if your custom breakpoint is smaller than largest default breakpoint (which is `2xl = 1536px`).

Usually such things extended with `theme.extend.{property}` but according to Tailwind [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#extending-the-default-breakpoints)

> If you want to add an additional small breakpoint, you can’t use
> `extend` because the small breakpoint would be added to the end of the
> breakpoint list, and breakpoints need to be sorted from smallest to
> largest in order to work as expected with a min-width breakpoint
> system. Instead, override the entire screens key

So your screens section of config should be

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '640px',
      'md': '768px',
      'lg': '1024px',
      'xl': '1280px',
      'pc': '1450px',
      '2xl': '1536px',
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
      white: {
        50: "#fefffe",
        150: "#4f4f4f",
        250: "#d7dce1",
        350: "rgb(127, 139, 153)",
        450: "rgb(235, 238, 241)",
        550: "rgb(104, 109, 115)",
        650: "rgb(228, 228, 231)",
      },
      red: {
        50: "#DA0037",
      },
      green: {
        50: "rgb(40, 191, 123)",
      },
      iceberg: {
        DEFAULT: "#DFF4F3",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#FFFFFF",
        300: "#FFFFFF",
        400: "#FFFFFF",
        500: "#DFF4F3",
        600: "#B9E7E5",
        700: "#93DAD7",
        800: "#6DCDC8",
        900: "#47C0BA",
      },
      "black-squeeze": {
        DEFAULT: "#DDE7F2",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#FFFFFF",
        300: "#FFFFFF",
        400: "#FFFFFF",
        500: "#DDE7F2",
        600: "#B8CDE4",
        700: "#93B3D6",
        800: "#6E99C8",
        900: "#497FBA",
      },
      "pigeon-post": {
        DEFAULT: "#B9BBDF",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#FFFFFF",
        300: "#FFFFFF",
        400: "#DCDDEF",
        500: "#B9BBDF",
        600: "#9699CF",
        700: "#7377BF",
        800: "#5055AF",
        900: "#40448C",
      },
      "polo-blue": {
        DEFAULT: "#878ECD",
        50: "#FFFFFF",
        100: "#FFFFFF",
        200: "#F3F4FA",
        300: "#CFD2EB",
        400: "#ABB0DC",
        500: "#878ECD",
        600: "#636CBE",
        700: "#4650A8",
        800: "#373F84",
        900: "#282E60",
      },
    },
    } 

  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou , it make sense , is it true for the colors also, after I added some colors I couldn't use the default colors.

Comment: No. To use default color you need NOT to override with `theme.colors` but relocate your colors to `theme.extend.colors`

Comment: Thankyou after your answer I read about it in tailwind it's clearly noted on it. I should start to read doc in more seriously, You are awesome :)